# What is the meaning of "Zen your computer"

Tags: meaning

I just reading a [post](http://www.lifehack.org/articles/productivity/10-ways-remove-the-distractions-that-keep-you-from-doing-the-best-work.html) about distraction. then I saw "Zen your computer" as an another step of how to get rid of distraction. I just curious what is that mean.

Comment: Could you provide more context and a link to the post?

Comment: It's not a common phrase, AFAIK. The author seems to think that reducing the distractions coming from your computer has a Zen-like quality - ostensibly referring to the meditation aspects of Zen.

Comment: Please post the relevant paragraph from the link.

Comment: There is at least one book called something like "Zen and the Computer".  Likely the caption is an oblique reference to such a book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article clearly describes what he means by Zen your computer.  To summarize it is to ELIMINATE all the distractions your computer is giving you and focus on the one thing you're working on.  Here is  The Wikipedia page on zen.[Zen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen)

Comment: illuminate? ???

Comment: @ michael.hor275k  well that was  typo full of irony.  Eliminate, i changed it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I think the author means applying a shallow Zen-like aesthetic.

She wants to turn off curiosity ??
  -- "Curiosity always wins, so go cold turkey and turn it off."

She makes product suggestions, etc. !?

-- "There’s a great app …"

-- "There's a great choice of apps …"

-- "There are all kinds of apps …"

You'll have to decide for yourself what Zen your computer means because the author may be missing her own point :-\